# VBA module call in userform to diff sheets

Tags: excel, vba

new and would like to ask if someone could possibly check my code to see where i'm making a mistake.

first, i've created a form with two textboxes and two buttons that will go and get two different directories and the associated files. this is done through a call to a function that loads the dir to the textboxes.

a button to call a function to navigate dir and get the file

```html
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'call selectFile function to select file
selectFile
End Sub
```

function to get workbooks into textboxes 1 and 2:

```html
Public Function selectFile()
Dim fileNamePath1 As String
Dim fileNamePath2 As String
Dim workbookFilePath1 As String
Dim workbookFilePath2 As String
    
On Error GoTo exit_
    
If workbookFilePath1 = Empty And workbookFilePath2 = Empty Then
    fileNamePath1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Open Workbook 1", MultiSelect:=False)
    workbookFilePath1 = Dir(fileNamePath1)
    'TextBox1.Text = workbookFilePath1
    TextBox1.Value = fileNamePath1
    
    fileNamePath2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Open Workbook 2", MultiSelect:=False)
    workbookFilePath2 = Dir(fileNamePath2)
    TextBox2.Value = fileNamePath2
    
    If fileNamePath1 = False Or fileNamePath2 = False Then
        MsgBox ("File selection was canceled.")
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End If

exit_:
End Function
```

up to here, the code is ok... can do better, but
here's where problems occur... i'd like to pass the directories as objects into the module to diff

button that executes module to diff:

```html
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    getTheWorkbooksToCompare(fileNamePath1, fileNamePath2)
End Sub
```

i know that i've changed myPath1 and myPath2 to Workbooks, where I've had them as strings before

diffing module

```html
Public Sub gettheWorkbooksToCompare(myPath1 As Workbook, myPath2 As Workbook)
Dim myExcelObj
Dim WorkbookObj1
Dim WorkbookObj2
Dim WorksheetObj1
Dim WorksheetObj2

Dim file1 As String
Dim file2 As String
Dim myWorksheetCounter As Integer
Dim i As Worksheet

Set myExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
myExcelObj.Visible = True

Set file1 = Dir(myPath1)
Set file2 = Dir(myPath2)

Set WorkbookObj1 = myExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(file1)
Set WorkbookObj2 = myExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(file2)
Set NewWorkbook = myExcelObj.Workbooks.Add

While WorkbookObj1 <> Null And WorkbookObj2 <> Null
'While WorkbookObj1.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count = WorkbookOjb2.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
    myWorksheetCounter = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
    myWorksheetCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count
    If WorksheetObj1.Worksheets.myWorksheetCounter = WorkbookObj2.Worksheets.myWorksheetCounter Then
        Set WorksheetObj1 = WorkbookObj1.Worksheets(myWorksheetCounter)
        Set WorksheetObj2 = WorkbookObj2.Worksheets(myWorksheetCounter)
        Set myNewWorksheetObj = NewWorkbook.Worksheets(myWorksheetCounter)

        For myWorksheetCounter = i To WorksheetObj1
            For myWorksheetCount = j To WorksheetOjb2
                'If cell.Value myWorksheetObj2.Range(cell.Address).Value Then
                If cell.Value = myWorksheetObj2.Range(cell.address).Value Then
                    myNewWorksheetObj.Range(cell.address).Value = cell.address.Value
                    myNewWorksheetObj.Range(cell.address).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                End If
            Next
                    
            'if doesn't work... use SaveChanges = True
            myNewWorksheetObj.Workbooks.Save() = True
                    
        Next
    Else
        MsgBox ("The worksheets are not the same worksheets." & vbNewLine & "Please try again.")
    End If
Wend

Set myExcelObj = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

So my question is... can someone please assist in seeing where i'm going wrong? essentially, i'm having some issues in trying to get this working.
much appreciated

i've gone through and cleaned up some areas a little bit... but now have a: "run time error '438': object doesn't support this propety or method" at the while loop code that i've updated the post with

Comment: Is anything happening at all when you click CommandButton1?

Could you post what errors you are receiving?  or what is happening in your attempts to run it?

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo on CommandButton1_Click

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    getTheWorkbooksToCompare(fileNamePath1, fileNamePath2)
End Sub


Public Sub gettheWorkbooksToCompare(myPath1 As Workbook, myPath2 As Workbook)
```

There might be something more, but your not capitalizing the "T" in getThe, but you call it that way.

Comment: hi thank you... i added the "The" part to try and be verbose so anayone could see my train of thought... i double checked in case too. :) still getting an error of: "expected function or variable" on the CommandButton1_Click() for getTheWorkbooksToCompare

Comment: also, if i change the code in the button to be: `Dim t1 As msforms.textbox   Dim t2 As msforms.txtbox   Call getTheWorkbooksToCompare(t1, t2)` i get an error inside of the getTheWorkbooksToCompare module, where `Set file1 =` is highlighted and the error reads: object required

Comment: OK.  I will take another look.  The error message gives a much better clue.

Comment: As far as the compare, you are declaring what kind of object it is, but you aren't defining an actual object.  Like for example.
"txtFirstName.Text"  or just textbox1.text... Whatever you named the actual textbox.  Instead of just saying, "I'm going to give you a textbox in the future" it wants to know WHICH ONE..